# AIOHTTP: web.run_app(app,port=9090) ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: asynchronous, python-asyncio, aiohttp, pytest-aiohttp

whenever i try to integrate templates in aiohttp im facing this issue 
i dont know where exactly the issue is from 
here is my code

```
from aiohttp import web
from routes import setup_routes
import aiohttp_jinja2
import jinja2

app = web.Application()
# app.add_routes([web.get('/', hello),
# web.get('verification/',email_verification)
# ])


setup_routes(app)
# aiohttp_jinja2.setup(app,loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(('C:\Users\madhumani\workspace\project-master\drfc\mxion\aiohttp\templates'))
aiohttp_jinja2.setup(app,loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader('templates')

web.run_app(app,port=9090)
```

if i remove that aiohttp_jinja2.setup line everything works fine
i  have followed everything mentioned in the docs for setting up templates but cant figure out the issue

Comment: Use a [raw string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081640/what-exactly-do-u-and-r-string-flags-do-and-what-are-raw-string-literals) for the path containing backslash characters: `r'C:\Users\madhumani\workspace\project-master\drfc\mxion\aiohttp\templates'`

Comment: You are missing a closing braces `)` on the jinja setup line